# Finding the equation real root.

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

where $c$ is a positive real number;

The equation $c .\ln(x) = x^2$ has a single real root. So what is the value of the number $c$?

How should I go about it? Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let consider

$$f(x)=c\ln x -x^2 \implies f'(x) =\frac c x -2x \implies f''(x)=-\frac c{x^2}-2$$

then find $x$ such that $f'(x)=0$ and $c$  such that $f(x)=0$.

$$f'(x) =\frac c x -2x =0 \implies x=\sqrt{\frac c 2}$$

with

$$f\left(\sqrt{\frac c 2}\right)=c \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac c 2}\right)-\frac c 2=0 \iff \sqrt{\frac c 2}=e^\frac12 \iff c=2e$$

and since $f(x)$ is convex this is the unique value such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: in 1'st derivative eq. => c = 2x^2 ,so x^2 = c/2
in f(x) eq. => clnx = x^2 => clnx = c/2 => lnx = 1/2, so x = e ^(1/2)
and finally c = 2e, am I right?

Comment: @AlanCostaGrey Yes, now we can use the condition $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @AlanCostaGrey Yes I obtain the same result. Since $f(x)$ is convex.

Comment: so the result is 2e, right?. Why didn't we use second derivative?

Comment: @AlanCostaGrey Second derivative is used for the convexity but we can also use only $f'(x)$.

Comment: okey thanks buddy !